# Cannot record with a Gradio audio input using dynamic layout

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gradio

I want to create an interface with `gradio` where I have an initially hidden audio input, that after some steps, e.g. receiving instructions, the user can record audio. But when I make the audio input visible it is unable to record.

```py
import gradio

with gradio.Blocks() as interface:
    recorder = gradio.Audio(source='microphone', type='filepath', visible=False)
    action_btn = gradio.Button('Start')
    def next_line(action):
        if action == 'Start':
            return {action_btn: 'Next', recorder: gradio.update(visible=True)}
        else:
            return {action_btn: 'Done', recorder: gradio.update(visible=False)}
    action_btn.click(next_line, inputs=[action_btn], outputs=[action_btn, recorder])
interface.launch(share=True)
```

Also, I am using it in a jupyter notebook at the moment for prototyping.

Can someone help me to workaround this issue, recording with a component that is sometimes hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a component solely to `outputs` makes it `interactive=False` by default.
Add your audio component to `inputs` to make it work:

```py
import gradio

with gradio.Blocks() as interface:
    recorder = gradio.Audio(source='microphone', type='filepath', visible=False)
    action_btn = gradio.Button('Start')
    def next_line(action, _):
        if action == 'Start':
            return {action_btn: 'Next', recorder: gradio.update(visible=True)}
        else:
            return {action_btn: 'Done', recorder: gradio.update(visible=False)}
    action_btn.click(next_line, inputs=[action_btn, recorder], outputs=[action_btn, recorder])
interface.launch(share=True)
```