# Use Start/Stop button to record live audio using Gradio app

Tags: python, audio, gradio

I want to add a button in my Gradio app to start/stop audio recording. Basically, what I am trying to do is place a button on the UI. When a user clicks on the this button(let's say "Speak"), then audio recoding starts and the button text changes to "Stop". When user clicks on the button again(which now says "Stop") then audio recording stops.

I was looking at this code: [Cannot record with a Gradio audio input using dynamic layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846512/cannot-record-with-a-gradio-audio-input-using-dynamic-layout/77021084#77021084)

The behaviour of the button is similar to what I need but I am unable to trigger audio player recoding.

Thank you for spending time to go through my query!

Sample layout:

[image]

```
import gradio


with gradio.Blocks() as interface:
    recorder = gradio.Audio(source='microphone', type='filepath', visible=False)
    action_btn = gradio.Button('Speak')

    def next_line(action, _):
        if action == 'Speak':
            return {action_btn: 'Next', recorder: recorder.start_recording}
        else:
            return {action_btn: 'Done', recorder: gradio.update(visible=False)}

    action_btn.click(next_line, inputs=[action_btn, recorder], outputs=[action_btn, recorder])

interface.launch(share=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out a solution. Hope it helps! You can also find it [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/use-start-stop-button-to-record-live-audio-using-gradio-app/53313).

```py
import gradio as gr


def click_js():
    return """function audioRecord() {
    var xPathRes = document.evaluate ('//*[@id="audio"]//button', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
    xPathRes.singleNodeValue.click();}"""


def action(btn):
    """Changes button text on click"""
    if btn == 'Speak': return 'Stop'
    else: return 'Speak'


def check_btn(btn):
    """Checks for correct button text before invoking transcribe()"""
    if btn != 'Speak': raise Exception('Recording...')


def transcribe():
    return 'Success'


with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    audio_box = gr.Audio(label="Audio", source="microphone", type="filepath", elem_id='audio')

    with gr.Row():
        audio_btn = gr.Button('Speak')
        clear = gr.Button("Clear")

    audio_btn.click(fn=action, inputs=audio_btn, outputs=audio_btn).\
      then(fn=lambda: None, _js=click_js()).\
      then(fn=check_btn, inputs=audio_btn).\
      success(fn=transcribe, outputs=msg)

clear.click(lambda: None, None, msg, queue=False)

demo.queue().launch(debug=True)
```